# Google Sheets Script, to collate a list of values that are then emailed

Tags: google-apps-script

I am creating a stocklist that I would like to be emailed every friday as to what is low or out of stock.

I have 3 sheets of different parts that each have a column to say "Place order" or "Out of stock".

I would like a sheet to be created weekly, with the name being the date, that compiles all stock that needs to be ordered and all the details about it. and then this information to be written to me via email.

I realise this is a big ask so any help is greatly appreciated.

I have managed to get the sheet to copy another sheet and delete all rows that contain the words "In Stock".

My code at the moment is as follows

```
function newsheetfororder() {
  var sheetname = "Order Form "
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  {
    var s1 = ss.getSheetByName("Fixings");
    ss.insertSheet(sheetname,0,{template:s1});      

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
    var rows = sheet.getDataRange(); 
    var numRows = rows.getNumRows(); 
    var values = rows.getValues(); 
    var rowsDeleted = 0; 

    for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) { 
      var row = values[i]; 
      if (row[0] == 'In Stock') { 
        sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted); rowsDeleted++; 
      }
    } 
  }; 
}
```

Comment: What have you tried already? We aren't going to just write your code for you.

Comment: I appreciate that but I am very new with script writing. I'm more looking for guidance as to what commands to use rather than the script being written for me

Comment: If you could inform me as to which command would create a new sheet, copy information over from different sheets and find the information I will try and work out the rest

Comment: Review the [Apps Script Spreadsheet API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet) and then also the [Apps Script Mail Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/)

Comment: I have managed to get it to copy over one sheet and delete the rows that contain "In Stock", what can I use to get the information from the other 2 sheets across?

this is my script at the moment

Comment: I would also like the name of the new sheet (order form) to include the date of the creation in it

Comment: To change the name, adjust the name... If you want to use parts of the date, then do that. You'll need a [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) variable. If you want to get data from 2 other sheets, then do that. Your script already gets data from 1 sheet, and makes changes based on that data. It should be trivial to get data from other sheets given the code you have already written. Writing data is then as simple as using `Range.setValue(value)` and `Range.setValues([[r1c1, r1c2 ...], [r2c1, r2c2 ...]])`